# How to upload file in readonly text from selenium using xpath as sendkeys won't work

Tags: java, html, angularjs, selenium, file-upload

This is the Structure:

`<input _ngcontent-c9="" class="form-field" placeholder="Upload Emote" readonly="" type="text">`

I have used the below code for uploading the file but sendkeys not working and I am not getting any error but unable to upload.

```
    WebElement uploadingEmote = adminDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Upload Emote']"));
    uploadingEmote.sendKeys("/home/smart/Downloads/EMO/(Heart).png");
```

But the above code is not working as the field is readonly.
Any help would be appreciated.

[this is the screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xFJD.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _code is not working_? Do you see any error? Update the question

Answer (score 0):

```
<input _ngcontent-c9="" class="form-field" placeholder="Upload Emote" readonly="" type="text">
```

your type of input field should be 'file' type if you want to upload a file

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```